# Custom Web Browser - To Load only my URL - Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser

I need a Portable web Browser, or any install-able (Windows) Browser, which will only load my URL.

Some thing Like I will have my Shortcut in the desktop, when User click, the Web browser with my URL loads.

Is it possible with portable Firefox to modify, I also need cookies to work along, thats the reason I need to find a custom Web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out a partial solution using

Mozilla Client Customization Kit , we can create a extension which allows to customize firefox upto certain limitations.

```
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cck/
```